# Spheres and converting formulas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, spherical-geometry

If the volume *V* of a sphere with radius *r* is *V=(4/3)πr^3*.  If the surface area is *s=4πr^2*, how can I express the volume as a function of the surface area *S*?  My first thought was to set them equal to each other but it doesn't seem like the right thing to do.  Any hints/help would be appreciated

-edit-
ok so from S=4πr^2, I got r=√(S/4π)...So now I am stuck as to what to do. Since I'm trying to do V(S)=?...I just replaced the r from V=(4/3)πr^3 with √(S/4π) but the answer doesn't correlate with the answer on the book. what am i doing wrong?

-edit-

V(S)=4/3π*(sqrt(S/4π)^3

V(S)=4/3π*((S^3/2)/(8π^3/2)

V(S)=(4Sπ^3/2)/(24π^3/2)

V(S)=(1Sπ^3/2)/(6π^3/2)

Answer should be:S/6*sqrt(S/π)...what did i do wrong?

Edit: V(S)=Sπ√π/6π√π

V(S)=S/6

Edit:
V=4/3π*r^3

S=4π*r^2

r^2=S/4π

r=sqrt(S/4π)

V(S)=4/3π*(sqrt(S/4π)^3

V(S)=4/3π*S√S/8π√π

V(S)=S√S/3*2√π

V(S)=S√S/6√π

Special thanks to J.M for helping me figure this out

Comment: The straight forward method involves solving for $r$ in one of the equations, replacing the $r$ in the other equation with the expression for $r$ you've just derived, and then solve for the volume. Can you follow this?

Comment: alright, I'm following you. so Since I want V(S): i should solve r for the S equation right? and then do the math?

Comment: That works. :) If you figure out the answer, you can post your solution to answer your question.

Comment: can you look at my edits and see what i did wrong?

Comment: You did try simplifying after replacing the $r$? Note also that $\sqrt{\frac{S}{4\pi}}$ is the same as $\frac12\sqrt{\frac{S}{\pi}}$.

Comment: should the 1/2 be cubed?

Comment: Ok so after distributing I got 4/3pi*(S^3/2)/(8π^3/2)

Comment: Huh? How'd you get to that? You need to show your steps.

Comment: I'm so lost lol i wrote what i did

Comment: Wait, I see now. Please note that `S^3/2` is quite ambiguous; better to write `S^(3/2)` or `(S^3)/2` as needed. Parentheses are cheap!

Comment: Haha alright, so what did i do wrong?

Comment: You could still cancel stuff. Note that $\pi^{3/2}=\pi\sqrt{\pi}$ and that you can still reduce $\frac48$ to lowest terms...

Comment: where do u get 4/8?

Comment: You already have $\frac{4\pi S\sqrt{S}}{3\times 8\pi\sqrt{\pi}}$. Can you see what cancels?

Comment: Ahhh now this make sense!. I finally got my answer. I am going to be typing my answer soon, so can you rewrite it so it looks nice?

Comment: actually do you mind rewritting my question? I can't answer my own question after some time

Comment: Just wait until it's okay to post your answer. :) At least you now know how it goes, right?

Answer (score 2):

$S=4r^2\pi \Rightarrow r^2=\frac{S}{4\pi} \Rightarrow r=\sqrt{\frac{S}{4\pi}}$

$V=\frac{4}{3}(\sqrt{\frac{S}{4\pi}})^3\pi \Rightarrow V=\frac{4}{3}\frac{S}{4\pi}\pi\sqrt{\frac{S}{4\pi}} \Rightarrow V=\frac{S}{3}\sqrt{\frac{S}{4\pi}} \Rightarrow V=\frac{S}{3}\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{\frac{S}{\pi}}\Rightarrow V=\frac{S}{6}\sqrt{\frac{S}{\pi}}$